# How do I use "ddev share" to share BOTH my drupal website AND mailhog?

Tags: ngrok, ddev

Is it possible to easily share both my drupal site and mailhog via ngrok using ddev share?  (ddev share is working great to share my site currently.)

I am *not* networking savvy, and have tried variations on specifying port, etc but with no luck.

In case it matters, this is a windows machine running ddev on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just run a separate ngrok command that shares the mailhog port. If you look at what `ddev share` does, it just does `ngrok http http://127.0.0.1:49156`, so we'll do the same with your mailhog port.

1. Expose a known specific port for mailhog directly at the host level (not going through ddev-router), so set `host_mailhog_port: 9999` in `.ddev/config.yaml` - this would need to be different for each project that's running at a given time.
2. Now run ngrok with `ngrok http http://127.0.0.1:9999` in a different window and you'll find the shared mailhog window.

It would be easy to create a [custom command](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/custom-commands/) that would do this for you, or even a custom command that would launch both share and ngrok-mailhog share.

Comment: This worked wonderfully.  Thank you!!!  The config.yaml setting was what I had been missing.